# Android version 4 and 5 does not accept our valid ssl certificate

Tags: android, ssl, web

We have a website ([https://ardbit.net](https://ardbit.net/)) with valid ssl certificate. from about 5 days ago android versions 4 and 5 does not accept this ssl certificate While until a few days ago, the site was visible in them without any problems. we did not make any changes to the site and ssl certifcates.
[android version 5 browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKKG.jpg)
Please help us to find the trouble and fix it.

Comment: Has the certificate expired?

Comment: No, it is valid until 2021